# How to convert unmanaged<CFData> to NSData?

Tags: swift, xcode6

I need to convert my Objective-C to Swift to get an image of a contact from the Address Book. But I get an error with for cast from `CFData` to `NSData` and I don't know how make this work. What can I do to make this work correctly?

In Objective-C:

```
ABRecordID contactID = ABRecordGetRecordID(contactRef);
ABAddressBookRef addressBook = ABAddressBookCreate();

ABRecordRef origContactRef = ABAddressBookGetPersonWithRecordID(addressBook, contactID);

if (ABPersonHasImageData(origContactRef)) {
    NSData *imgData = (NSData*)ABPersonCopyImageDataWithFormat(origContactRef, kABPersonImageFormatOriginalSize);
    img = [UIImage imageWithData: imgData]; 

    [imgData release];
}

CFRelease(addressBook);

return img;
```

In Swift:

```
var image: UIImage!

if ABPersonHasImageData(person) {
    var imgData = (ABPersonCopyImageDataWithFormat(person, kABPersonImageFormatOriginalSize))
    image = UIImage.imageWithData(imgData) //Here get the error 
}
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

As explained in
[Working with Cocoa Data Types](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/mac/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/BuildingCocoaApps/WorkingWithCocoaDataTypes.html), you have to  convert the unmanaged object to a memory managed object with `takeUnretainedValue()` or `takeRetainedValue()`.
In your case

```
if (ABPersonHasImageData(person)) {
    let imgData = ABPersonCopyImageDataWithFormat(person, kABPersonImageFormatOriginalSize).takeRetainedValue()
    let image = UIImage(data: imgData)
}
```

because `ABPersonCopyImageDataWithFormat()` returns a (+1) retained value.

Comment: It fails when image is nil

Comment: @AlešOskarKocur: Thank you for the feedback.  In the question, this code is preceded by an ABPersonHasImageData() check, I have added that to the answer as well now for clarity. Does that solve your concern?

Answer (score 2):

```
if let imgData = ABPersonCopyImageDataWithFormat(person, kABPersonImageFormatOriginalSize)?.takeUnretainedValue() {
   if let image = UIImage(data: imgData) {
      //Here's your UIImage
   }
}
```

Comment: Please explain your answer.

Comment: First I don't think we need to retain the image data, secind since it might be nil, we don't need an image with nil data. I had runtime error with Martin R's answer and this solved the problem.

Comment: `ABPersonCopyImageDataWithFormat()` has "Copy" in its name and returns a (+1) retained value. You have to call `takeRetainedValue()`, otherwise it will leak memory. – `takeRetainedValue()` does not retain the image data, but tells the Swift runtime that the return value is (+1) retained, so that it will be released appropriately.