# How do you import a DER certificate in swift?

Tags: macos, swift

So it seems as though a bunch of methods have changed which have broken things in my current codebase.  I'm currently getting the following error:

> Cannot convert the expression's type '(CFAllocator!, data: @lvalue NSData)' to type 'CFData!'

Here's the relevant code:

```
let mainbun = NSBundle.pathForResource("mainkey", ofType: "der", inDirectory: "/myapppath")
var key: NSData = NSData(base64EncodedString: mainbun!, options: nil)!
var turntocert: SecCertificateRef = SecCertificateCreateWithData(kCFAllocatorDefault, data: key)
```

I have it working with a bridging header but i would still like to just be able to create the certificate reference directly in swift.

---

UPDATE:
this works

```
var bundle: NSBundle = NSBundle.mainBundle()
var mainbun = bundle.pathForResource("keyfile", ofType: "der")
var key: NSData = NSData(contentsOfFile: mainbun!)!
var turntocert: SecCertificateRef =
SecCertificateCreateWithData(kCFAllocatorDefault, key).takeRetainedValue()
```

Comment: Is this for certificate pinning and are you using AFNetworking?

Comment: @bbarnhart yes it is for certificate pinning and no i am not using AFNetworking

Comment: This one is decent. I'd spend a bit more time on formatting. Your error is buried at the end of a paragraph. Your code's indentation is wrong in the solution. And scrollbars on code is always a bad sign. You know, I've seen much worse questions (than the three of yours I just reviewed) get upvotes. Maybe swift devs are just cheap with their love? That's always a possibility. Communities attract different types of individuals. For example, the C++ tag attracts the most hateful souls you can imagine. Don't go in there.  You'd already be autobanned.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In Swift, `SecCertificateCreateWithData` returns an `Unmanaged` type.  You need to get the value of the unmanaged reference with `takeRetainedValue()`.

```
let mainbun = NSBundle.pathForResource("mainkey", ofType: "der", inDirectory: "/myapppath")
var key: NSData = NSData(base64EncodedString: mainbun!, options: nil)!
var turntocert: SecCertificateRef = 
    SecCertificateCreateWithData(kCFAllocatorDefault, key).takeRetainedValue()
```

The core problem you have is converting `CFData` to `NSData`.  [See this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25262542/how-to-convert-unmanagedcfdata-to-nsdata)

Comment: sweet thanks, i had to make a few other small changes but that was my main issue